# Correctly define path to test properties using @TestPropertySource (Spring Boot 2)

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-test

I have a following hierarchy in my Spring Boot 2 test folder

```
 test/
      java/
           package.name/
                        SpringBootTest.java

       resources/
                 test.properties
```

SpringBootTest has a code like

```
@RunWith (SpringRunner.class)
@TestPropertySource(locations = {"/resources/test.properties"})
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT, 
             properties = {"management.port=0"})
public class SwaggerExtractorTest { ... }
```

I also tried to use locations = {"test.properties"} with the file located just next to the java class itself, and some other paths, but it was always the error **class path resource [...] cannot be opened because it does not exist**.

Ideally I like to have path for @TestPropertySource that I can place on different levels of test code hierarchy without change, that is, relative to some top level.

What would be a correct way to set this path?

Comment: Remove `/resources/` from the location.

Comment: Make sure that `test.properties` moved into `target/test-classes`. Maybe the problem is there...

Comment: try ::: @TestPropertySource("classpath:test.properties")

Comment: @M.Deinum it would then expect file next to test file (same classpath). However moving it there won't help.

Comment: I for some reason assumed it was prefixed with `classpath:` (I hate mondays). You shoudl use `classpath:test.properties`. `src/test/resources` is the root of the test classpath (just as `src/test/java` but for `.java` files).

Answer (score 4):

Assuming the `test/resources` folder you are referring to is the `src/test/resources` folder used by your Maven/Gradle build...

`@TestPropertySource("/test.properties")` and `@TestPropertySource("classpath:test.properties")` are equivalent, and both should work for referencing a `test.properties` file in the root of the classpath.

Answer (score 0):

This fixed it for me.

Make sure your test resources folder is set up in sources. Below are the instructions for IntelliJ:

1. Click on the project tab.
2. Right click on the project and select “Open Module Settings”
3. Under Project Settings, select “Modules”
4. Under sources make sure your test resources folder is listed. Mine looks like:

[image: IntelliJ sources setup]