# how to define @TestPropertySource(location)?

Tags: unit-testing, spring-boot

i'm trying to add a `test.properties` file in my test package.
the structure is

```
test->java->  -> test.java
              -> resource -> test.properties
```

and my command is

```
   @RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
    @ContextConfiguration(classes = Publish.class)
    @TestPropertySource(locations = "classpath:/src/test/java/resources/test.properties")
    public class Test {


...
}
```

but i always keep getting this

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to add PropertySource to Environment
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [/src/test/java/resources/test.properties] cannot be opened because it does not exist
```

i have few other variants and i still get this error, how can i solve this??

Other variants:

```
 @TestPropertySource(locations = "classpath:/test.properties")

 @TestPropertySource(locations = "classpath:/resources/test.properties")

 @TestPropertySource(locations = "classpath:test.properties")
```

another similar question was asked but i din't seem to solve my problem  [stackOverflow Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56933129/correctly-define-path-to-test-properties-using-testpropertysource-spring-boot)

Comment: `contrak/contrak/src/test/java/resources/test.properties` is kind of self explainatory. You dont have such structure (starting with contrak/contrak)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be

```
 @TestPropertySource(locations = "classpath:/yourPackage/thatContainResource/test.properties")
```

`src` is not on runtime and is not a part of classpath.

But most importantly, your directory structure is wrong. `resources` should be next to `java` like this:

[image]

By putting your resources into sources (like you did), they got filtered out.

Comment: you mean `/resource/test.properties`??? if i go with `test -> resource -> test.properties` structure??

Comment: no, it will be just `test.properties` then. everything from `resources` directory is put into bundle (eg into ZIP) makes it available on classpath.

Comment: is it possible to change the structure and still make it work??

Comment: You could try to modify some maven configs - but why would you? 99.9% of maven projects looks like that.

Comment: just curious, i tried using another structure `test -> awesome -> anothertest.properties` to see it will work, but din't, seems like any resources must in resource folder

Comment: you wyould have to add `awesome` as resources directory in maven, then it would work. But it is just common convention. Its better not to break it if you dont have to imho.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196866/discussion-between-humming-bird-and-antoniossss).

Comment: out of curiosity how can i add it??